# Does geography (spartial type) T-SQL supports in the functions and EF?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, t-sql, spatial

I generate the function

```
    if (geofence != null)
    {
        geofenceParameter = new ObjectParameter("geofence", geofence);
    }
    else
    {
        geofenceParameter = new ObjectParameter("geofence", typeof(System.Data.Spatial.DbGeography));
    }

base.ExecuteFunction<AssetData>("FindLastGeofenceEnterOrExit", assetIdParameter, geofenceParameter, startDateParameter, isEnterParameter);
```

on SQL server it looks like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_FindLastGeofenceEnterOrExit]
@assetId bigint,
@geofence geography,
@startDate datetime,
@isEnter bit
AS
```

But when i try to call that function VS throws the exception:
[image]

Can't figure out does EF supports it or not. I use EF 6.0.0.0

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Thank you Marc, I will follow your suggestion

Comment: you have verified the geofence object type as created the object, you verified that the object is a valid geometry, such things have brought me problems in similar projects

Comment: @marc_s thanks for the above, I was also falling foul of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF6 definitely supports geography types in stored procedures (as did EF5).  Although I've only worked database first, I pulled this (modified slightly and simplified) from the EDMX file.  Hope it helps.

```
public virtual ObjectResult<MyClass> MyStoredProcedure(System.Data.Spatial.DbGeography location, MergeOption mergeOption)
{
    var locationParameter = location != null ?
        new ObjectParameter("location", location) :
        new ObjectParameter("location", typeof(System.Data.Spatial.DbGeography));

    // EDIT: Neglected to copy this part in during original post
    return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<MyClass>("MyStoredProcedure", mergeOption, locationParameter);
}
```